# How to install .dictionary file to iOS10?

Tags: ios, dictionary, ios9, ios10

I want to add my custom dictionary to iOS Dictionary Built-In
[image]

I have created a .dictionary file since 2014 to translate English to Khmer.

With iOS 7, I port my dictionary to iOS Built-in via Dictionary Appender 
[image]

but since Apple Remove Dictionary Appender from AppStore I cannot port my .dictionary file to use as dictionary package in iOS anymore.

[image: iOS10 : Settings > General > Dictionaries]

So how can I port/add my custom dictionary to iOS10?

Thank advance
Mony

Comment: I wrote about it in this post
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/242296/how-to-add-another-integrated-dictionary-to-ios9/283092#283092
Hope it's useful for you

Comment: Thank you! That is a good dictionary that may use Google Translate source. But I want to use with my own .dictionary built

Answer (score 3):

Solution for JB is you can download one of the apple standard dictionaries that you wouldn't need in ios settings, then go (with iFunbox) to the folder /var/MobileAsset/Assets/com_apple_MobileAsset_DictionaryServices_dictionary2 and in a single folder(if you installed only one dictionary) with unreadable name you will find subfolder /AssetData/your dictionary name.dictionary
Replace this dictionary with yours, but keep the original apple dictionary name. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

You simply can't. The app Dictionary.appender is no longer available. We can only guess why apple does not provide a standard way to add dictionaries since, at least in my opinion the built in dictionary is one of the greatest features of iOS/MacOS.
If you jailbreak you can add them but without that, there is no standard way of doing it.

Comment: Thank you. Can you show me how to do it with the Jailbreak device.

Comment: I decided not to jailbreak my new iPhone, so I don't have exact instructions, you should look up on the internetz. As far as I remember it was as simple as putting the desired .dictionary file in some directory. Here is a link, don't know if it works tho :) https://www.reddit.com/r/jailbreak/comments/1xcm88/tutorial_add_custom_dictionaries_to_ibooks_on/